# when I run my package ssis throws me an error, the job zips the files and move it to another folder and delete the original c2 audit file?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an ssis package with a for each loop container and script task in it. It constantly throws me the following error message,

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

My script is Microsoft Visual C# 2012

```
{
        //set the value to local variables
        string filename = Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
        string inputfilepath = Dts.Variables["$Package::C2_Audit"].Value.ToString() + filename;
        string archpath = Dts.Variables["$Package::C2_Audit_Archived"].Value.ToString() +
               filename.Replace(".", ".zip");


        //Create Zip File and then Add file to it
        using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(archpath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            zip.CreateEntryFromFile(inputfilepath, filename);
        }

        //Delete the file that is compressed 
        File.Delete(inputfilepath);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

}
```

Can any one help me with this to stop the error from coming.
I have also made the propagation to false and maximum error count to 0. Thanks,

Comment: Can you isolate which line this occurs on? Or does it occur before the code starts? Are you certain all the paths are correct and you have sufficient access? Is this running interactively inside the SSIS editor or is it running in SQL Agent?

Comment: You should at least implement a
`try...catch`
around any file system actions.